# How to find the new files after a specific time point in windows ?(command line)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I know there is a way in linux to filter all file generated after a specific time.
But how could we do that in windows command line ? Or in bash .
For example, I have three files in a folder. After 10/10/2016, 12:12:54, a new files was generated into this folder and I need to know the new file's name,size and path. 
Or, 
I don't know when the new files will be generated. I want to check each 10 mins. If there are some new files generated after a specific , I can get the file's name, path and size.
I search something about that , I know I can use `forfiles /P directory /S /D +08/01/2013` to do that. But it will displays all the files which are modified after 08/01/2013 under directory. But I want it displays the folders in directory  and all files in directory folder(not in its sub directory).

Comment: Type `forfiles /?` Don't use `/s`. See `timeout /?` and `goto /?`. Type `Help`.

Comment: As an alternative to timeout you could use the Task Scheduler, to run the batch-file (I guess) every ten minutes.

Comment: `forfiles` check the last modification date only, but not the creation date; furthermore, it does not care about the time at all, so you cannot use it to check whether ther are new files created since the last 10 minutes (if I got your intention right). What about a completely different approach: to store a list of files (see `dir /?`) into a text file and to compare that with the actually available files every 10 minutes? this avoids date/time maths which is not natively supported in batch...

Comment: @aschipfl I can do that, but I don't think it is an efficient way to do that.

Comment: It depends on the amount of files; for few files only, it might be way easier than doing date/time maths in batch (which you had to write on your own, unless you lend some code from another language); for thousands of files, it is perhaps not a quite good solution... Anyway, the great advantage with the temporary file approach is you will always catch all files that have been created since the last call; when checking the file ages, you might miss files that have been created during the previous script execution...

Comment: @aschipfl I know I it depends on the number of files. I have at least 4 thousands files to check, so that's why I don't want to use that. I need to use batch.

Comment: Hm... and how many files will be created within the 10 minutes interval? ...just a side note: if `forfiles` was fast enough for your first attempts, `dir` will likely suffice either...

Comment: @aschipfl I am not sure how many files will be generated in 10 intervals, it varies. But even though the num is pretty small, the total num of existed files will be at least 4000. Even though I assume only one new files will be generated in 10 mins, I still need to compare 4000 files names with 4001 files name.

Comment: Check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39988291) to see what I meant by using temporary file lists to accomplish your task; I tried it for my temporary directory which contains a few thousand files and it worked perfectly fine and quite fast...

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not show any own efforts to solve your task, I decided to provide a script that returns a list of files created since the previous execution. It does not check the file creation time stamp, because date/time maths is not natively supported in pure [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solutions. Instead it generates a list of files, stores it in a temporary file and compares it with a previously saved list.

Opposed to relying on file time stamps, this will for sure recognise every new files. When checking the time stamps, files may be considered as new since the last run erroneously or new files may not be recognised erroneously, particularly such files that are created during execution of the script.

So here is the code:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "TARGET=D:\Data"    & rem // (path to the directory to observe)
set "PATTERN=*.*"       & rem // (search pattern for matching files)
set "LIST=%TEMP%\%~n0"  & rem // (file base name of the list files)
set "FIRSTALL=#"        & rem /* (defines behaviour upon first run:
                          rem     set to anything to return all files;
                          rem     set to empty to return no files) */

rem /* Determine which list file exists, ensure there is only one,
rem    then toggle between file name extensions `.one`/`.two`: */
set "LISTOLD=%LIST%.two"
set "LISTNEW=%LIST%.one"
if exist "%LIST%.one" (
    if not exist "%LIST%.two" (
        set "LISTOLD=%LIST%.one"
        set "LISTNEW=%LIST%.two"
    ) else (
        erase "%LIST%.one"
        if defined FIRSTALL (
            > "%LIST%.two" rem/
        ) else (
            erase "%LIST%.two"
        )
    )
) else (
    if not exist "%LIST%.two" (
        if defined FIRSTALL (
            > "%LIST%.two" rem/
        )
    )
)

rem /* Create new list file, containing list of matching files
rem    sorted by creation date in ascending order: */
> "%LISTNEW%" dir /B /A:-D /O:D /T:C "%TARGET%\%PATTERN%"
if not exist "%LISTOLD%" (
    > nul 2>&1 copy /Y "%LISTNEW%" "%LISTOLD%"
)

rem // Search new list file for items not present in old one:
2> nul findstr /V /I /X /L /G:"%LISTOLD%" "%LISTNEW%"
if ErrorLevel 2 type "%LISTNEW%"

rem // Delete old list file:
erase "%LISTOLD%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

The first time the script runs, all files in the monitored directory are returned, unless you change `set "FIRSTALL=#"` to `set "FIRSTALL="`, in which case no files are returned the first time.

The core command is `findstr` which is configured so that the old list file provides literal search strings for being used to search the new list file and to return not matching lines, so the output are those lines of the new list file which do not occur in the old one.

---

Supposing the script is saved as `new-files-since-last-run.bat`, you could wrap around another tiny script that constitutes an endless loop with a polling rate of 10 minutes, like this:

```dos
@echo off
:LOOP
> nul timeout /T 600 /NOBREAK
call "%~dp0new-files-since-last-run.bat"
goto :LOOP
```

Setting up Windows Task Scheduler might be a better option though.